# react-redux not connecting store to react component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm working with `react v0.14.3`, `redux v3.0.5`, `react-redux v4.02` and `immutable v3.7.6`.
Im trying to wire together the redux store with a react component using `react-redux` but I cant seem to get the store data to be passed down to the components. My console is clean of errors and In my redux-devtools I see the whole state tree. In my `index.js` component I have the `Provider` component setup correctly. Im hoping its a simple error I may have overlooked.

#### Store & Provider

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './../reducers/rootReducer.js';
import DevToolsx from './../components/DevTools/Devtools.jsx';

// var createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)(createStore);

var finalCreateStore = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware),
  // window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
  DevToolsx.instrument()
)(createStore);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  var store = finalCreateStore(rootReducer, initialState);
  return store;
}
```

```js
//index.js
var store = configureStore();

render(
  (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={history} >
        ...
      </Router>
    </Provider>

    ),document.getElementById('app'));
```

#### Reducer

```js
//imports are in my codebase

var sample = I.List.of(
  I.Map({
    sneakerImg: 'someLinkToSneakerImg1',
    sneakerName: 'Air Jordane 1',
    price: 120,
    condition: 10,
    size: 12,
    reRelease: true,
    quantity: 1
  })
);

export function dashShoppingCartReducer (state = sample, action ) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case CHECKOUT:
      return handleCheckout(state, action.cartPayload);

    case REMOVE_SNEAKER_FROM_CART:
      return handleRemoveSneakerFromCart(state, action.sneakerToRemove);

    case RECEIVE_SNEAKERS_IN_CART:
      return handleReceiveSneakersInCart(state, action.cartSneakers);

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

#### rootReducer.js

```js
//imports are in my codebase

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  landing: landingReducer,
  dashboard: dashboardReducer,
  listings: listingsReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

#### dashboardReducer

```js
//imports are in my codebase

export const dashboardReducer = combineReducers({
  userSneakers: dashSharedReducer,
  shoppingCart: dashShoppingCartReducer,
});
```

#### DashCart.jsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import DashCartTable from './DashCartTable.jsx';
import * as DashCartActions from './../../actionCreators/Dashboard/DashShoppingCart.js';
function DashCart (props) {

  var checkOut = () => props.actions.checkout(props.cartSneakers);

  return (
    <div className="DashCart">
      <DashCartTable cartSneakers={props.cartSneakers} actions={props.actions}></DashCartTable>
      <button onClick={checkOut} className="checkout btn btn-default">CheckOut</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    cartSneakers: state.dashboard.shoppingCart
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(DashCartActions, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(DashCart);
```

#### DashCartTable.jsx

```js
import React from 'react';
function DashCartItem (props) {

  var remove = () =>  props.actions.removeSneakerFromCart(props.key);

  return (
    <div className="DashCartItem">
      <div className="pull-left">
        <img className="itemImg"src="./../../../assets/images/creator.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div className="content pull-left">
        <h3 className="itemTitle">{props.sneaker.sneakerName}</h3>
        <p>Condition: {props.sneaker.condition}</p>
        <p>Size: {props.sneaker.size}</p>
        <p>Re-release: {props.sneaker.reRelease}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="content pull-right">
        <p>${props.sneaker.price}</p>
        <p>Quantity: {props.sneaker.quantity}</p>
        <button onClick={remove} className="btn btn-default">Remove</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DashCartItem;
```

#### DashCartItem.jsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import DashCartItem from './DashCartItem.jsx';
function DashCartTable (props) {

  var DashCartItemsList = props.cartSneakers.map((sneaker, key) => {
    <DashCartItem sneaker={sneaker} key={key} remove={props.removeSneakerFromCart}></DashCartItem>
  });

  return (
    <div className="DashCartTable">
      {DashCartItemsList}
    </div>
  );
}

export default DashCartTable;
```

Comment: Please also include your store and reducer code.

Comment: okay ill do that now

Comment: Also the file that defines configureStore. It's important to see how the state is structured.

Comment: One more thing: the rootReducer file.

Comment: @DavidWalsh The odd thing is that the checkout actionCreator get dispatched if I click checkout with the payload from the store state tree. But the components don't get populated.

Comment: @DavidWalsh Added the rootReducer underneath the dashboardReducer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>The problem definitely lies here:</s>

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    cartSneakers: state.dashboard.shoppingCart
  }
}
```

Assuming `dashShoppingCartReducer` lives in `dashboardReducer.js`, that `shoppingCart` key does not exist. Either remove the `shoppingCart` key from that line above, or add a `shoppingCart` key to your state.

#### Update

Disregard the above. I didn't realise you were using nested `combineReducers`.

I now think the problem lies with `DashCartItem`. Since you're using ImmutableJS, you should be accessing the fields with `props.sneaker.get('sneakerName')` instead of `props.sneaker.sneakerName`.

#### Update 2

Be careful how you use arrow functions. They only have an implicit return if you *don't* use braces.

The following won't work:

```
var DashCartItemsList = props.cartSneakers.map((sneaker, key) => {
  <DashCartItem sneaker={sneaker} key={key} remove={props.removeSneakerFromCart}></DashCartItem>
});
```

Instead, change it to:

```
var DashCartItemsList = props.cartSneakers.map((sneaker, key) => {
  return <DashCartItem sneaker={sneaker} key={key} remove={props.removeSneakerFromCart}></DashCartItem>
});
```

Or to utilise the implicit return, use parentheses instead.

```
var DashCartItemsList = props.cartSneakers.map((sneaker, key) => (
  <DashCartItem sneaker={sneaker} key={key} remove={props.removeSneakerFromCart}></DashCartItem>
));
```

Comment: The `dashShoppingCartReducer` does live inside the `dashboardReducer`, In the devtools it shows you the state tree and it has the following 
```
state:{
  dashboard:{
     shoppingCart:{
        0: {..}
     }
  }
}
```

Im just not sure why the component doesn't receive it.

Comment: Where is that `shoppingCart` defined in your code? It's missing from the sample object.

Comment: it is defined inside the dashboard combineReducer I used combine reducer, once to combine all the dashboard reducers, and a scond time to combine it with all the app reducers. inside the first combine reducer there is the shoppingCart.

Comment: OK. I now understand your reducer setup better. I now think the problem has to do with how you're using ImmutableJS. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for not ditching me :) . I implemented what you suggested and It still didn't work out. I tried using dot nation and the page renders without the data. Since the reducer states are immutable I also attempted to use `getIn()` within the mapStateToProps() that errors out that getIn() was not a function and nothing was rendered. Could it maybe be something in the components? maybe the map() inside of DashCartTable.jsx?

Comment: Try installing React dev tools. Check that each component has the properties you expect. That way you can narrow down the problem. https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools

Comment: So everything within the DashCartTable.jsx does not render. What is inside of there are the DashCartItems that are created as I `map()` over items inside shoppingCart of the store. This is what the react-devtools tells me.

Comment: Ah hah! There is a problem with your map function. I've documented the solution above.

Comment: Tears of joy my friend. Thank you soo much! Quick question are you the same david walsh from davidwalsh.name? If so do you have pay pal so I can buy you a beer? I would upvote your post but I cant b/c I don't have 15 rep points.

Comment: Nope. Different person. Don't worry about the rep. Marking it as the correct answer also gives points.